# Extracting delimited strings from a paragraph

Tags: php, regex

I need to get all **{SOME_STRING}** from a paragraph as an array. For example :

```
Bla bla bla some {first} some string bla {second} bla bla .....
```

I have to get them like this array :

```
$array[0] = "first";
$array[1] = "second";
```

This is the REGEX pattern for **{SOME_STRING}** : `\{.+}`

Which method can i use ?

Comment: @yi_H: Search engines do not give such nice answers as stockoverlfow does.

Comment: and in general stackoverflow doesn't teach you how to solve problems alone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = "Bla bla bla some {first} some string bla {second} bla bla .....";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/\{(.+?)\}/", $str, $matches);
$array = $matches[1];

var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "first"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "second"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dogbert, can you teach me why we are using this : `$array = $matches[1];` ?  I'm reading php.net documentation about preg_match_all but i can't understood.

Comment: The regex uses a capture group `(.+?)`, so `$matches[0]` contains the complete matched strings `{first}` and `{second}` in this case, while `$matches[1]` contains the matches by the first capture group. Try doing `var_dump($matches)` and you'll understand better.

Comment: first group -> `{first}' , second group -> `first` Now i understood. Thanks !